# One - to -one mapping using non primary key

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I have two tables:

Table1 :
{
id:primary key
name:
email:
}

Table2:
Lid: primary key
tname:
email:
}

In both the cases email is neither primary key, nor the foreign. Is it possible to establish one-to-one mapping between both of these tables for the column email. I am using xml for mapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
<many-to-one class="Table2Entity" name="Table2Entity" property-ref="Email">
  <column name="Email" />
</many-to-one>
```

however you get errors if you also map email as property an table1 because column email would be mapped twice